# I have some trouble with proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I have follow theorem:
Let X is not Empty
$$W = \left\{\alpha _{1} x_{1} + \alpha _{2} x_{2} + \alpha _{3} x_{3} + ... \alpha _{n} x_{n} | x _{i}\in X , \alpha \in F \right\} \Rightarrow W = <X>$$

Proof:
1)Lets check that M is subspace
$$a,b \in W$$
$$a = \left\{ \alpha _{1}x_{1}+ \alpha _{2}x_{2} + \alpha _{3}x_{3}+...+ \alpha _{n}x_{n} \right\} 
b = \left\{ \beta _{1}x_{1}+ \beta _{2}x_{2} + \beta _{3}x_{3}+...+ \beta _{n}x_{n} \right\}$$
$$a + b = \left\{ (\alpha_{1} + \beta_{1})x_{1}+ (\alpha_{2} + \beta_{2})x_{2} + (\alpha_{3} + \beta_{3})x_{3}+...+ (\alpha_{n} + \beta_{n})x_{n} \right\}\in W$$
and check for multiply by the scalar

$$\alpha *a = \alpha _{1}\alpha+ \alpha _{2}\alpha+ \alpha _{3}\alpha+...+ \alpha _{n}\alpha$$
2)$$X\subseteq W (x_{i} * 1 = x_{i}) \forall x \in X \Rightarrow x\in W\Rightarrow x_{i} \in X \Rightarrow x_{i}\in W\Rightarrow x_{i} = \alpha_{1}x_{1}+ \alpha_{2}x_{2}+...+ \alpha_{n}x_{n}$$
where 
$$\alpha_{i} = 0$$
3) $$\left<X \right> = \bigcap_{\alpha}^{}{}M_{\alpha} \subseteq W$$

4) $$\forall a = \left\{ \alpha _{1}x_{1}+ \alpha _{2}x_{2} + \alpha _{3}x_{3}+...+ \alpha _{n}x_{n} \right\} \in W \Rightarrow W\subseteq \left< X \right>$$

What does number 3 mean? Why is this fair?

Comment: Could you first define $M_{\alpha}$ in 3)?

Comment: $$M_{\alpha}$$ It's the set of Subspaces that contain X

Comment: Then 3) is clear, right?

Comment: $$X = \left\{l_{1},l_{2},l_{3} \right\}$$

$$M_{1}=\left\{l_{1},l_{2},l_{3},v_{1} \right\}$$
$$M_{2}=\left\{l_{1},l_{2},l_{3},v_{1},v_{2} \right\}$$
$$M_{3}=\left\{l_{1},l_{2},l_{3},v_{1},v_{2},v_{3} \right\}$$
$$\bigcap_{\alpha  = 1}^{3}{}M_{\alpha} =\left\{l_{1},l_{2},l_{3},v_{1} \right\}$$

$$so,\:  why\: can\: we\: say\: that\: v_{1}\: \in\: W?$$

Comment: It is the intersection of **all** subspaces containing $X$, not just of $3$ subspaces. You need to review the definition of $\cap_{\alpha}M_{\alpha}$.